# Combine my network with my neighbors network

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, wan

My network and my neighbors network are connected (we share my server). We both have our own WAN-connection to the internet. Right now we use the following setup:

Neighbor:
Internet  --> router (192.168.1.1, DHCP off) --> network devices (pc’s with static IP’s using 192.168.1.1 as gateway)

My setup:
Internet --> router (192.168.1.2, DHCP on) --> network devices (all automatically determined IP’s through DHCP)

The two networks are connected with a network cable between a switch at my house and a switch at my neighbor’s house.

In essence this all works fine. But if my neighbour doesn’t specify a static IP on his devices they receive an IP from my dhcp-server and they use my internet connection to go online.

So is there a way to have 2 DHCP servers enabled on my network. One for my neighbour to use and one for me? So that we both use our own internet connections but still remain connected to each other.

I’m guessing there must be a simple solution but I cannot seem to find one. Who has any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no "easy solution" to use two DHCP servers on the network. DHCP is first come first served, so which ever server responds first will be the one the configuration is pulled from.

You can set up DHCP servers to give different settings to different computers based on MAC address. However, the software built in to consumer grade routers do not support things like that. 3rd party firmware that would support it (DD-WRT or similar) I would not call the DHCP setup process "easy" to support different results based on MAC addresses.

Your best option, without buying more hardware, is stop using DHCP on both networks and configure your network to use static IP's too.